# Retrieving counts of consecutive events from wide dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am working with a dataset that is in a wide format in R. It is a user generated dataset, with each row per `UserID` showing consecutive events per date. Here is a mock example of the type of data I am working with:

```
df<-structure(list(UserID = c("hdyyu-192", "yeui-1893", "dnnd-1882", "nopr-738", "ieka-1728"), 
                   `05/06/2021` = c("Activity B", "Activity A", "Activity B", "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `06/06/2021` = c("Activity B", "Activity A", "Activity A", "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `07/06/2021` = c("Activity D","Activity A", NA, "Activity C", "Activity D"), 
                   `08/06/2021` = c("Activity A","Activity B", NA, "Activity B", "Activity A"), 
                   `09/06/2021` = c("Activity A","Activity B", NA, "Activity B", "Activity C"), 
                   `10/06/2021` = c("Activity C",NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                   `11/06/2021` = c("Activity B", NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-5L))


head(df)

# A tibble: 5 x 8
  UserID    `05/06/2021` `06/06/2021` `07/06/2021` `08/06/2021` `09/06/2021` `10/06/2021` `11/06/2021`
  <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1 hdyyu-192 Activity B   Activity B   Activity D   Activity A   Activity A   Activity C   Activity B  
2 yeui-1893 Activity A   Activity A   Activity A   Activity B   Activity B   NA           NA          
3 dnnd-1882 Activity B   Activity A   NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
4 nopr-738  Activity C   Activity C   Activity C   Activity B   Activity B   NA           NA          
5 ieka-1728 Activity D   Activity D   Activity D   Activity A   Activity C   NA           NA
```

What I am trying to do is count the frequency of consecutive events; in other words, the frequency the antecedent/consequent event.

Here's the desired output:

```
#desired outcome

Antecedent   |   Consequent   |  Count

Activity A   |   Activity A   |    3
Activity A   |   Activity B   |    1
Activity A   |   Activity C   |    1

........................................

Activity D   |  Activity A   |    2
Activity D   |  Activity B   |    0
Activity D   |  Activity C   |    0
Activity D   |  Activity D   |    2
```

Can someone kindly suggest an approach in R that would let me achieve this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-UserID) %>% 
  group_by(UserID) %>% 
  mutate(aux = str_c(lag(value), value, sep = "-")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% select(aux) %>% 
  mutate(aux2 = "count") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = aux, names_from = aux2, 
     values_from = aux2, values_fn = length) %>% drop_na(aux) %>%
  separate(aux, into = c("Antecedent", "Consequent"), sep = "-") %>% 
  arrange(Antecedent, Consequent)

#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Antecedent Consequent count
#>    <chr>      <chr>      <int>
#>  1 Activity A Activity A     3
#>  2 Activity A Activity B     1
#>  3 Activity A Activity C     2
#>  4 Activity B Activity A     1
#>  5 Activity B Activity B     3
#>  6 Activity B Activity D     1
#>  7 Activity C Activity B     2
#>  8 Activity C Activity C     2
#>  9 Activity D Activity A     2
#> 10 Activity D Activity D     2
```

---

In case one is interested in showing also the zero counts:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-UserID) %>% 
  group_by(UserID) %>% 
  mutate(aux = str_c(lag(value), value, sep = "-")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% select(aux) %>% 
  mutate(aux2 = "count") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = aux, names_from = aux2, 
     values_from = aux2, values_fn = length) %>% drop_na(aux) %>% 
  separate(aux, into = c("Antecedent", "Consequent"), sep = "-") %>% 
  bind_rows(df[-1] %>% unlist %>% as.vector() %>% unique %>% 
              expand_grid(Antecedent = ., Consequent = .) ) %>% 
  drop_na(c(Antecedent, Consequent)) %>% 
  group_by(Antecedent, Consequent) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count, na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(Antecedent, Consequent)

#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    Antecedent Consequent count
#>    <chr>      <chr>      <int>
#>  1 Activity A Activity A     3
#>  2 Activity A Activity B     1
#>  3 Activity A Activity C     2
#>  4 Activity A Activity D     0
#>  5 Activity B Activity A     1
#>  6 Activity B Activity B     3
#>  7 Activity B Activity C     0
#>  8 Activity B Activity D     1
#>  9 Activity C Activity A     0
#> 10 Activity C Activity B     2
#> 11 Activity C Activity C     2
#> 12 Activity C Activity D     0
#> 13 Activity D Activity A     2
#> 14 Activity D Activity B     0
#> 15 Activity D Activity C     0
#> 16 Activity D Activity D     2
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do using string searches. We can create all possible combinations with `expand.grid` and then use `do.call` to convert them to strings, doing the same on `df` (without the `UserID` column) and just use `stringr::str_count()` to get the number of instances in each row, the sum being the total number of times it's occurred in `df`. This helps us maintain the ordering you want.

Note, we need to use a lookahead in the regex to count overlapping instances.

```r
library(stringr)

activities <- paste0("Activity ", LETTERS[1:5])
activities_df <- expand.grid(activities, activities)

activities_df$count <- sapply(
  do.call(paste, activities_df),
  \(x) sum(str_count(do.call(paste, df[,-1]), paste0("(?=", x, ")")))
)

head(activities_df)
#>         Var1       Var2 count
#> 1 Activity A Activity A     3
#> 2 Activity B Activity A     1
#> 3 Activity C Activity A     0
#> 4 Activity D Activity A     2
#> 5 Activity E Activity A     0
#> 6 Activity A Activity B     1
```

<sub>Note that `\(x)` is the shorthand for `function(x)` in `R >= 4.1.0`, just change to `function(x)` if using a previous version.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
DT <- melt(df,id.vars = "UserID",variable.name = 'Timestamp',value.name = 'Activity')
DT[,TimeStamp:=as.Date(Timestamp,format='%d/%m/%Y')]
DT <- DT[order(Timestamp)][,Activity_prec:=shift(Activity),by=.(UserID)]
DT[!is.na(Activity_prec)&!is.na(Activity),.(Count=.N),by=.(Activity_prec,Activity)][
   order(Activity_prec,Activity)]

    Activity_prec   Activity Count
           <char>     <char> <int>
 1:    Activity A Activity A     3
 2:    Activity A Activity B     1
 3:    Activity A Activity C     2
 4:    Activity B Activity A     1
 5:    Activity B Activity B     3
 6:    Activity B Activity D     1
 7:    Activity C Activity B     2
 8:    Activity C Activity C     2
 9:    Activity D Activity A     2
10:    Activity D Activity D     2
```